# Debug manifest .mpd

Tags: mpeg-dash

After activating CORS on my webserver I have run my manifest on dash conformance webtool finding several errors that I can not interpret, at the moment I am not able to get the ABR behavior,Can i ask for help to understand how to fix the bug?

https://allibrante.com/live/manifest.mpd

Below some log reported from the Dash confromance webtool, for more details is better run the manifest on their webtool

Thanks a lot!

> #### error: moov-1:trak-1:mdia-1:minf-1:stbl-1:stsd-1
>
> #### SampleDescription sdType must be 'mp4v', 'avc1', 'encv', 'hev1','hvc1', or 'vp09'('mp4v', 'avc1', 'encv', 'hev1','hvc1','vp09')
>
> Warning: Unknown atom found "avcC": video sample descriptions would
>   not normally contain this Warning: Unknown atom found "pasp": video
>   sample descriptions would not normally contain this Brand 'lmsg' not
>   found as a compatible brand for the last segment (number 3); violates
>   Section 3.2.3. of Interoperability Point DASH264: If the MPD@type is
>   equal to "dynamic" or if it includes MPD@profile attribute in-cludes
>   "urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011", then: if the Media Segment is
>   the last Media Segment in the Representation, this Me-dia Segment
>   shall carry the 'lmsg' compatibility brand tfdt base media decode time
>   1658.000000 not equal to accumulated decode time 0.000000 for track 1 for the first fragment of the movie. This software does not handle
>   incomplete presentations. Applying correction.
>
> #### error:
>
> #### Buffer underrun conformance error: first (and only one reported here) for sample 1 of run 1 of track fragment 1 of fragment 1 of track
>
> id 1 (sample absolute file offset 1356, fragment absolute file offset
>   860, bandwidth: 7591)

-

> 'tkhd' alternateGroup must be 0 not 1 Validate_ES_Descriptor: ES_ID
>   should be 0 not 2 in media tracks
>
> WARNING: unknown sample table atom 'sgpd' WARNING: unknown mvex atom
>   'trep' WARNING: unknown/unexpected atom 'meta' Brand 'lmsg' not found
>   as a compatible brand for the last segment (number 3); violates
>   Section 3.2.3. of Interoperability Point DASH264: If the MPD@type is
>   equal to "dynamic" or if it includes MPD@profile attribute in-cludes
>   "urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011", then: if the Media Segment is
>   the last Media Segment in the Representation, this Me-dia Segment
>   shall carry the 'lmsg' compatibility brand tfdt base media decode time
>   1657.984000 not equal to accumulated decode time 0.000000 for track 2 for the first fragment of the movie. This software does not handle
>   incomplete presentations. Applying correction.
>
> #### error:
>
> #### grouping_type roll in sbgp is not found for any sgpd in moof number 1
>
> #### error:
>
> #### grouping_type roll in sbgp is not found for any sgpd in moof number 1
>
> #### error:
>
> #### grouping_type roll in sbgp is not found for any sgpd in moof number 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the majority of your problems is spelled out in the error message: `This software does not handle incomplete presentations`. You are trying to validate a live stream, and this tool does not currently have that capability.

With respect to the sample description issue, it looks like the validator does not recognise avc3 content (ie where the parameter sets are inband rather than in the initialisation segment). I would consider this a bug and suggest you raise an issue at https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/Conformance-and-reference-source/issues.

Comment: Thanks for raply, i currently use mp4box to live segment adaptive streaming, may i which could be another tool for this scope?

Comment: I was thinking about an encoding error about resolution, the problem is that abr don't work

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean when you say "abr don't work". In the dashif reference player, manual adaptation works with no error in Chrome on Windows. However, the `@bandwidth` numbers don't look right - these would normally be in bits per second, whereas you appear to have used kilobits. This would cause any player always to pick the top representation.

Comment: Thanks a lot: by adding specific bandwidth as encoding bitrate it work! And you are sayd me that the conformance dash web tool report can be wrong? I need to investigate, but know it work, thanks